# How to Configure Multiple Plugins in Mypy?

Tags: python-3.x, plugins, mypy

I want to use both the numpy and the pydantic plugins for mypy, I tried the following in the `mypy.ini`:

```
[mypy]
plugins = [ numpy.typing.mypy_plugin, pydantic.mypy ]
# ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be configured as comma-separated string instead of an actual list, see the [docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html#confval-plugins). This works:

```
[mypy]
plugins = numpy.typing.mypy_plugin, pydantic.mypy
# ...
```